# Add more vertical space in a table row

Tags: tables

I have this table but I need more vertical space in the rows for fractions, they are very tight.

[image]

```
 \begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
 \hline
 \rowcolor{green} $x$ & $g(x)$ \\ \hline
 $0$ &  \\ \hline
$3$ &  \\ \hline
$-2$ &  \\ \hline
$\dfrac{3}{4}$ &  \\ \hline
 $\dfrac{-1}{2}$ &  \\ \hline
 & $0$ \\ \hline
 & $5$ \\ \hline
 & $-3$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `tabularray` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation of @clara answer, where is increased vertical space around cells contents for 5pt and and reorganized table preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{2}{Q[c,wd=2em, mode=dmath]}}, % <--- changed
             row{1}  = {bg=green},
             rowsep  = 5pt                              % <--- added
             }
x            & g(x) \\
0            &      \\
3            &      \\
-2           &      \\
\frac{3}{4}  &      \\
\frac{-1}{2} &      \\
             & 0    \\
             & 5    \\
             & -3   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Updated: use `dmath` mode.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec = {Q[c,m]Q[c,m]},
hlines,vlines,
row{1}  = {bg=green},
cells   = {mode=dmath},
}
x            & g(x) \\
0            &      \\
3            &      \\
-2           &      \\
\frac{3}{4}  &      \\
\frac{-1}{2} &      \\
             & 0    \\
             & 5    \\
             & -3   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice (+1). But perhaps `cells={$}` could be added to the format? Only an idea

Comment: thanks, now is fine. .. just for curiosity what's means Q[c,m]

Comment: @user89940 `Q` is a column type from the `tabularray` package. The `c` makes the cells horizontally centred, the `m` centres them vertically

Comment: thanks so much!

Comment: @JuanCastaño Thank you for your reminder.

Comment: @user89940 I have upadte my answer, now, you dont't need to use `\dfrac` manually, it is dispalystyle for all cell.

Answer (score 4):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}[hvlines,colortbl-like,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\rowcolor{green} $x$ & $g(x)$ \\ 
 $0$ &  \\ 
$3$ &  \\ 
$-2$ &  \\ 
$\dfrac{3}{4}$ &  \\ 
 $\dfrac{-1}{2}$ &  \\ 
 & $0$ \\ 
 & $5$ \\ 
 & $-3$ \\
\end{NiceTabular} 

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
 {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
 \hline
 \rowcolor{green} $x$ & $g(x)$ \\ \hline
 $0$ &  \\ \hline
$3$ &  \\ \hline
$-2$ &  \\ \hline
$\dfrac{3}{4}$ &  \\ \hline
 $-\dfrac{1}{2}$ &  \\ \hline
 & $0$ \\ \hline
 & $5$ \\ \hline
 & $-3$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image]